# cd No such file or directory. Also cd Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I am installing Tomcat 7 for Openboxes.
I followed step by step on the official tutorial on 
[Ubuntu 18.04 --> Tomcat](https://docs.openboxes.com/en/develop/installation/ubuntu1804/tomcat/).

---

My Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS.

Tomcat version is 7.0.104

---

On this step

```
    $ sudo groupadd tomcat
    $ sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat 
    $ sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.104
    # sudo chmod +x /opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh
```

---

When I execute the last line `chmod +x /opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh`

It returns `chmod: cannot access '/opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh': No such file or directory.`

So I tried to cd into the directory

It returns: `bash: cd /opt/tomcat/bin/: Permission denied`

Then I said "WTF" and tried `sudo su`

Then I successfully got into the `/opt/tomcat/bin/`

I tried same code on sudo su mode,

but the result is the same: `chmod: cannot access '/opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh': No such file or directory.`

---

What should I do on this step?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.

---

I made a mistake on `cd /opt/tomcat/bin/` after `sudo su`.

I mistakenly typed `chmod +x */sh` instead of `*.sh`.

---

I need to train my eyes...

Thanks!